# Почему запись типа post_type не подхватывает singe?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, в чем дело. Зарегистрировал запись `type_post=retraining`, и он не хочет подхватывать созданный макет типа `single.php`. Пробовал создать еще файл `single-retraining.php`, но все равно не хочет подхватывать созданный макет страницы. Вот страница которая выводит посты
Вот шаблон для вывода страниц, `archive-retraining.php`

```
<?php
                    /*
                    Template Name: Пост 2
                    Template post_type: retraining
                    */
                    ?>
                    Вот мой код single-retraining.php
                    <?php get_header(); ?>




                            <div class="main-title">
                              <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
                                <div class="row justify-content-md-center p-0 m-0">
                                  <div class="col-md-10">
                                      <div class="bread">
                                        <?php if( function_exists('kama_breadcrumbs') ) kama_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                                      </div>
                                    <div class="headings">
                                        <h1>
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                      while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_post();
                      ?>        
                      <main class="content">
                        <div class="row justify-content-md-center p-0 m-0">
                          <div class="col-md-9">    
                            <?php the_content(); ?>    
                            <button type="button" data-target="modal" class="show-modal btn btn-primary btn-lg">Записаться на курс</button>
                            </div>
                          <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="close">&times;</div>
                          <h4>Заполните поля</h4>
                          <p>Что-то</p>
                          <div class="modal-form">
                            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2edbf6a" title="Контактная форма 1"]') ?>  
                          </div> 
                        </div>      
                      </div>
                      </main>




                        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Вот код регистрации записи в `function.php`

```
function register_retraining_entities() {
                  $retraining_args = array(
                    'public' => true,
                    'label'  => null,
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => 'Переподготовка',
                        'singular_name' => 'Переподготовка',
                        'add_new'            => 'Добавить курс Переподготовки',
                        'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление курса Переподготовки',
                        'new_item' => 'Новый курс Переподготовки',
                        'all_items' => 'Все курсы Переподготовки',
                        'view_item' => 'Смотреть курс Переподготовки',
                        'search_items'       => 'Искать курс Переподготовки',
                        'not_found'          => 'Не найдено',
                        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине',
                        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
                        'menu_name'          => 'Переподготовка',
                    ),
                    'menu_position' => 6,
                    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'retraining' ),
                     'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                    
                    'has_archive' => true
                  );
                  register_post_type( 'retraining', $retraining_args );
                }

                add_action( 'init', 'register_retraining_entities' );
                add_image_size('retraining-theme', 384, 384, true);
```

Вот код `archive-retraining.php` который отвечает за вывод текста

```
<?php
            /*
            Template Name: Переподготовка
            */
            ?>

            <?php get_header(); ?>


                    <div class="main-title">
                      <div class="container-fluid p-0 m-0">
                        <div class="row justify-content-md-center p-0 m-0">
                          <div class="col-md-10">
                              <div class="bread">
                                <?php if( function_exists('kama_breadcrumbs') ) kama_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                              </div>
                            <div class="headings">
                                <h1>
                                    <?php wp_title("", true); ?>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <main class="content">
                  <div class="news-items">
                    <div class="row p-0 m-0">
                        
                                        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
                                            <?php
                  $args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 999,
              'post_type' => 'retraining'
            );
                  $posts = get_posts ($args);


            foreach( $posts as $post){
              setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 p-0 m-0">

                            <div class="card"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <!-- Содержимое карточки -->
                                <!-- Изображение -->

                  

                            <div class="card text-white">
                              <img class="card-img" <?php the_post_thumbnail('events-theme'); ?>
                              <!-- Текстовый контент -->
                              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                  <h4 class="events-title"><?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="events-footer">
                                    <?php the_field( 'date_start' ); ?>
                                    <?php the_field( 'date_end' ); ?>
                                    <?php the_field( 'date_main' ); ?>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                            </a>
                            </div></div>

                      <?php } wp_reset_postdata();?>
                       
                        

                        
                        </div>
                        </main>


            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Не могу понять, почему он не подхватывает стили. Попробовал перерегистрировать запись, и он вообще перестал переходить по ссылке на эту запись, но при этом ее выводит
[image]

при этом саму ссылку он видит, но не переходит